# How to make keyPress uppercase in Java?

Tags: java, keypress, keyevent, capslock

```
localRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);
```

I have no clue how to make this keypress an uppercase keypress. I attempted to press VK_SHIFT and release afterwards, however that didn't work. Would it work to press the capslock button? If so, how do I do it? Is it just VK_CAPS?

Comment: You might want to include what language this is in...Java?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot to add that. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might work. It presses the shift button, presses yours then releases.

```
localrobot.keyPress (KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT); 
localrobot.keyPress (keyCode); //Your keycode(your letter)

localrobot.keyRelease (KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT); 
localrobot.keyRelease (keyCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
localRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
localRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);
localRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F);
localRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

Or:

```
localRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
localRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
localRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);
localRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F);
localRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
localRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
```