# Java robot type uppercase, lowercase and symbols from string

Tags: java

How would I make this type uppercase characters too? And symbols? For example, to make the robot type the string "TeSt!//123$" or anything else similar?

```
void sendKeys(Robot robot, String keys) {
    for (char c : keys.toCharArray()) {
        int keyCode = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(c);
        if (KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED == keyCode) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "Key code not found for character '" + c + "'");
        }
        robot.keyPress(keyCode);
        robot.delay(100);
        robot.keyRelease(keyCode);
        robot.delay(100);
    }
}
```

I tried changing the code, still no luck.

```
void sendKeys(Robot robot, String keys) {
    for (char c : keys.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.println(c);
        int keyCode = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(c);
        if (KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED == keyCode) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Key code not found for character '" + c + "'");
        }
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            robot.keyPress(keyCode);
            robot.delay(100);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            robot.keyRelease(keyCode);
            robot.delay(100);
        } else {
            robot.keyPress(keyCode);
            robot.delay(100);
            robot.keyRelease(keyCode);
            robot.delay(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Slashes don't require any changes (depending on keyboard?). Have you tried pressing the meta keys when not lower case, or alphanumeric? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311831/how-to-make-keypress-uppercase-in-java

Comment: I tried and edited the code, it types "test123" instead of "TeSt123"

Comment: You need to release the character before shift

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tested, but I think you'd need something like

```
    if (needsShift(c)) {
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.delay(100);
    } 
    robot.keyPress(keyCode);
    robot.delay(100);
    robot.keyRelease(keyCode);
    robot.delay(100);
    }
    if (needsShift(c)) {
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.delay(100);
    }
```

Where you can start the method just for uppercase

```
private boolean needsShift(Character c) {
    return Character.isUpperCase(c);
}
```

Then you need to extend that to include a Map of characters to keycodes that require the shift key to reach. Note: the keycodes are associated to a specific keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with typing out capital letters using the **shift + letter** combo. Sometimes it worked, other times it did not.

I just used the **caps lock** button:

```java
for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
    }

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(c));
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(c));

    if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
    }
    super.delay(super.typingDelay);
}
```

**This answer only covers capital letters**. The super `delay` method is this in case you are wondering:

```java
public void delay(Long delay) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(delay);
    } catch (
            InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But you can use the built in robot `delay` method:

```java
robot.delay(500) // in ms
```